# Make app exclusive for iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, xcode, autolayout

I have an app that uses a lot of customisation. I built it using the 4" display, but when I go to the 3.5" it's sort of a mess. And then when I fix the 3.5", the 4" is messed up. Is there a way to make the app exclusive to the iPhone 5? Like how some apps are exclusive to certain versions of iOS? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, however you'll probably get a good answer if you post a question asking how to make your layout work on both screen sizes.

Comment: Both the screen, there a dozens of answers...

Comment: Xclusive5, check in very first method if it deviceTypeIsNot==@"ios5"{ showAlert to to quit the app}

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Apple will reject your app if you do this. You should never quit an app if the device is not supported, it should not have installed in the first place. Stickerbox you should just make you UI either change to fit both screen sizes or place the UI in a scrollview thus making it scroll on 3.5".

Comment: @rckoenes: that is why i said  show alert and ask user to quit the app, i did not  asked to exit(0). :p

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Apple will still reject your app, even if you tell the user that there device is not supported.

Comment: ok... today I more thing I learnt about ios :)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you can make it exclusive to iPhone 5, but if you're struggling with this like I was you should look up how to use constraints in IB. I never knew they existed but they fixed the alignment issue for me.

Comment: Did you just answer your own question?

Comment: I guess his friend answered from his system and account :P\

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can limit which devices your app can run on by adding the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in your Info.plist file.

[Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/B_DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) gives a list of different capabilities and how they are supported on different devices.

Unfortunately for your case there is no single hardware feature exclusive to iPhone 5 on this table. The closest you can come is requiring `bluetooth-le` but that still includes iPhone 4S.